# Spring reactive - Update nested objects in a list, then save the parent object

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming

I have a root object, which has a nested list of objects. I need to get access to that nested list of objects, preform some actions against them and then save the results back in.

I seem to be getting myself tripped up on nested `flatMaps`.

The best I've managed to come up with is:

```
public Flux<Face> scanSingleVideo(@PathVariable final String id) {

    // Reactive MongoDB Find by ID
    return videoRepository.findById(id)

            // A single video is returned, the video has an ArrayList of thumbnails
            .flatMapMany(video -> Flux.fromIterable(video.getThumbnails()))

            // Each thumbnail has a 'path' value which is just a string
            .map(Thumbnail::getPath)

            // Passing the path into a function which does some business work. The function returns a Flux of faces
            .flatMap(faceService::detectFaces);

            // Q: How can I get these new objects into an array on the Thumbnail, then save the video object with the updated thumbnail? 
}
```

But I'm stuck now on if this is even the right direction. For context here is the two domains I'm working with

**Video object**

```
public class Video {
    // {..}
    List<Thumbnail> thumbnails = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**Thumbnail object**

```
public class Thumbnail {
    // {..}
    String path;

    Set<Face> faces = new HashSet<>();
}
```

---

The first attempt I had felt close as it set the new objects on the `Thumbnail`, but is very ugly and feels like I've gone wrong somewhere or missed a key method I could use. This does however work.

```
public Mono<Video> scanSingleVideo(@PathVariable final String id) {
    return videoRepository.findById(id)
            .flatMap(video -> {
                video.getThumbnails().forEach(thumbnail -> faceService
                        .detectFaces(thumbnail.getPath())
                        .flatMap(face -> {
                            thumbnail.getFaces().add(face);

                            return Mono.just(thumbnail);
                        }).flatMap(t -> {
                            video.getThumbnails().add(t);

                            return videoRepository.save(video);
                        }).subscribe());

                return videoRepository.save(video);
            });
}
```

I don't like the nested subscribe, but I'm not sure how else to approach this.

---

**Edit**: For anyone that comes across this, you can clean my 'working' attempt up slightly, but I still don't think it's correct.

```
public Mono<Video> scanSingleVideo(@PathVariable final String id) {
    return videoRepository.findById(id)
            .flatMap(video -> {
                video.getThumbnails().forEach(thumbnail -> faceService
                        .detectFaces(thumbnail.getPath())
                        .flatMap(face -> getPublisher(video, thumbnail, face))
                        .distinct()
                        .subscribe());

                return videoRepository.save(video);
            });
}

private Publisher<? extends Video> getPublisher(Video video, Thumbnail thumbnail, Face face) {
    thumbnail.getFaces().add(face);
    video.getThumbnails().add(thumbnail);

    return videoRepository.save(video);
}
```